# How can I access a property of a constructor through an instance of that constructor?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, construct

Here the constructor is Animal. It has two instances duck and beagle. There is a function named eat() which is actually a prototype of Animal.

```
function Animal() {
  this.color = "brown";
 }

Animal.prototype = {
  constructor: Animal,
  eat: function() {
    console.log("nom nom nom");
  }
};

let duck = Object.create(Animal.prototype); 
let beagle = Object.create(Animal.prototype); 
duck.eat();
console.log(duck.color);
```

here

```
duck.eat()
```

works, but duck must also inherit the color brown right ? Why am I not able to access it using

```
duck.color ?
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no `color` property on `Animal.prototype`. It is dynamically added to the object when the constructor function is called… but you aren't calling the constructor function at all.

If you want to create an instance of a class, then call the constructor function. Don't use `Object.create`.

```js
function Animal() {
  this.color = "brown";
 }

Animal.prototype = {
  eat: function() {
    console.log("nom nom nom");
  }
};

let duck = new Animal();
let beagle = new Animal();
duck.eat();
console.log(duck.color);
```

Answer (score 0):

No It wont inherit,

Please read the definition of `Object.create`.

"The Object.create() method creates a new object, using an existing object as the prototype of the newly created object"

Means, only `prototype will be copied from existing object on will be placed in newly create object's prototype`

Here `color` is instance variable not prototype. Hence wont be available in newly created `duck` object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create